# Getting error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Trying to do a delete but I keep getting error "SQL command not properly ended"

script

```
CREATE TABLE reservation_daily_elements
( 
resort         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
room VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
reservation_date  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) 
); 


INSERT INTO reservation_daily_elements (resort, room, reservation_date) 
VALUES ('210', '112', '20-JAN-2019');
```

query

```
delete room from reservation_daily_elements
where resort = '210'
and room = '112'
and reservation_date > '16-JAN-2019';
```

Comment: "delete room from ..." should be "delete from ..."

Comment: remove "room" between "delete" and "from"

Comment: Just checking, but do you expect that the value in the room column is cleared, or do you expect to remove the whole record? The former requires an UPDATE, the latter a DELETE.

Comment: and this would not delete the whole table?

Comment: More info on [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). It's used to change values. For example to a NULL to clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below just remove room from your query

```
delete from reservation_daily_elements
where resort = '210'
and room = '112'
and reservation_date > '16-JAN-2019';
```

Comment: this will not delete the whole table?

Comment: @Josh no this will not delete whole table . it will delete only those values where condition will meet

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
delete from reservation_daily_elements
where resort = '210'
  and room = '112'
  and reservation_date > '16-JAN-2019';
```